# how to print nodes names

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nodes, scene

im new for swift sprite kit and I just learning about nodes and this stuff. as I play with the nodes I wonder how can I print to console all the names of the nodes that I currently have on my scene. I read and try the enumerateChildNodes but I didn't get it right and failed while doing that. 
is there any option to do what im trying to?

Comment: Please show what you tried and how it failed ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to visit all the nodes in your scene you can define a visit method

```
import SpriteKit

extension SKNode {
    func visit() {
        print(self.name)
        children.forEach { $0.visit() }
    }
}
```

Finally in your scene just write

```
class Scene:SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)

        visit() // <--
    }
}
```

### Example

```
let scene = Scene()
scene.name = "scene"
let a = SKNode()
a.name = "a"
let b = SKNode()
b.name = "b"
let c = SKNode()
c.name = "c"
let d = SKNode()
d.name = "d"

a.addChild(b)
b.addChild(c)

scene.addChild(a)
scene.addChild(d)

scene.visit()
```

Result

```
Optional("scene")
Optional("a")
Optional("b")
Optional("c")
Optional("d")
```